# How to select the data for the x axis to run a graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

With this dataframe

```
            id power     hr    fr    VE     VO2    VCO2  PETCO2 percent_VO2 percent_power group
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25  88.75 22.75 22.75 0.73900 0.66700 39.2925    49.34068      21.73913   CHD
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40  93.25 23.00 23.75 0.81975 0.71500 39.6200    54.73210      34.78261   CHD
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55  99.75 22.75 26.75 0.95125 0.85400 41.4100    63.51193      47.82609   CHD
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70 109.75 23.00 32.50 1.07525 1.04700 42.0150    71.79102      60.86957   CHD
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85 118.75 22.75 39.50 1.19900 1.25125 41.8425    80.05341      73.91304   CHD
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100 127.00 26.00 48.25 1.34575 1.51850 41.0950    89.85144      86.95652   CHD
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115 135.75 28.00 55.75 1.49775 1.76025 40.7275   100.00000     100.00000   CHD
8  AL13-PRD-C1    25  69.50 16.50 24.00 0.66125 0.58050 31.2275    41.36691      19.23077   CHD
9  AL13-PRD-C1    40  73.00 17.50 26.50 0.74850 0.66425 32.1025    46.82515      30.76923   CHD
10 AL13-PRD-C1    55  83.25 15.50 29.00 0.85500 0.79425 33.6650    53.48764      42.30769   CHD
11 AL13-PRD-C1    70  93.75 16.00 36.50 0.98450 0.99925 34.5325    61.58899      53.84615   CHD
12 AL13-PRD-C1    85 104.50 16.00 44.75 1.14950 1.23475 34.4225    71.91117      65.38462   CHD
13 AL13-PRD-C1   100 114.25 19.25 55.25 1.34650 1.48375 33.1800    84.23522      76.92308   CHD
14 AL13-PRD-C1   115 125.25 20.75 63.75 1.45100 1.65775 32.6450    90.77260      88.46154   CHD
15 AL13-PRD-C1   130 136.25 24.75 78.00 1.59850 1.89075 30.9000   100.00000     100.00000   CHD
16 BM06-PRD-S1    25 119.25 18.25 19.00 0.61675 0.58225 37.6425    48.87084      25.00000 noCHD
17 BM06-PRD-S1    40 126.00 18.00 20.75 0.71700 0.65950 39.2175    56.81458      40.00000 noCHD
18 BM06-PRD-S1    55 133.50 20.75 25.00 0.86275 0.82750 41.2150    68.36371      55.00000 noCHD
19 BM06-PRD-S1    70 147.25 18.25 29.00 0.98575 1.04550 41.7050    78.11014      70.00000 noCHD
20 BM06-PRD-S1    85 158.50 22.25 39.25 1.13000 1.30525 41.1425    89.54041      85.00000 noCHD
21 BM06-PRD-S1   100 168.75 27.75 51.00 1.26200 1.61150 38.8925   100.00000     100.00000 noCHD
22 CB19-PRD-S1    25  98.75 18.50 25.00 0.88350 0.80475 40.7550    36.15715      13.15789 noCHD
23 CB19-PRD-S1    40  98.25 20.00 25.50 0.94575 0.82900 41.4675    38.70473      21.05263 noCHD
24 CB19-PRD-S1    55 102.00 19.75 28.50 1.08125 0.95800 42.2775    44.25005      28.94737 noCHD
25 CB19-PRD-S1    70 107.50 20.50 34.25 1.24400 1.14275 42.6450    50.91058      36.84211 noCHD
26 CB19-PRD-S1    85 111.00 21.25 35.50 1.30475 1.19925 43.3600    53.39677      44.73684 noCHD
27 CB19-PRD-S1   100 117.25 21.50 40.25 1.47350 1.42225 44.2650    60.30284      52.63158 noCHD
28 CB19-PRD-S1   115 123.00 22.75 47.00 1.67900 1.68475 44.6400    68.71291      60.52632 noCHD
29 CB19-PRD-S1   130 129.50 24.50 52.50 1.79075 1.87950 44.3425    73.28627      68.42105 noCHD
30 CB19-PRD-S1   145 135.50 25.25 59.50 1.96000 2.13525 44.7300    80.21281      76.31579 noCHD
31 CB19-PRD-S1   160 145.25 26.75 64.50 2.04050 2.28350 43.8825    83.50726      84.21053 noCHD
32 CB19-PRD-S1   175 151.25 30.50 83.00 2.34425 2.76050 41.6025    95.93820      92.10526 noCHD
33 CB19-PRD-S1   190 161.75 33.75 92.25 2.44350 2.96850 40.0400   100.00000     100.00000 noCHD
```

I am running this code:

```
ggscatter(dftest, x = "percent_power", y = "PETCO2", color = "group") +
  stat_cor(label.x = 20, label.y = 2.8) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 20, label.y = 0.5, 
                        formula = y ~ poly(x, 2),
                        aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) +
  xlab("Percentage of power (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("PETC", O[2]," (mmHg)")))
```

I would like to run the code but just by selecting the data from 65 to 75 % percent of power (x axis). We would get a new equation based on the new selection.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can subset `dftest` to the points of interest with `dftest[dftest$percent_power>=65 & dftest$percent_power<=75,]` but there are not enough points in that range to fit your model.

Comment: Where does ggscatter come from?

Comment: it comes from ggpubr

Comment: thank you @KentJohnson, it is working very well. I can not accept your answer because you should put your comment as an "Answer"

Comment: Thanks @MaxStudent, it's an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset `dftest` to the points of interest with `dftest[dftest$percent_power>=65 & dftest$percent_power<=75,]` but there are not enough points in that range to fit your model.